# JS: Relative positioning of tooltip on right of icon

Tags: javascript, html, css, tooltip

I have an icon, and when you hover over it, I would like to have a custom CSS tooltip appear to the right of the icon.  Whether or not you scroll up or down the page, the tooltip will always need to appear to the right of the icon.

And no, I don't want to use any plugins.  I just want a little JS/CSS to get the job done.  If you use JQuery, it needs to be compatible with v1.7, and JQuery-UI: v1.8.

In addition, **it needs to be compatible with IE 6 and 7**.

I would prefer to leave my elements as siblings, but it looks like under certain circumstances the div that appears needs to be a child element, so it's OK if the HTML needs to be changed.

**HTML:**

```
<img src="" class="icon">ICON<img/>

<div class="demo">
    STUFF<br/>
    STUFF<br/>
    STUFF<br/>
    STUFF<br/>
    STUFF<br/>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.demo {
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 265px;
    height: 110px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid #333;
}

.demo:after, .demo:before {
    border: solid transparent;
    content: ' ';
    height: 0;
    right: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
}

.demo:after {
    border-width: 11px;
    border-right-color: #ccc;
    top: 13px;
}

.demo:before {
    border-width: 14px;
    border-right-color: #333;
    top: 10px;
}
```

**Live Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/49Js3/16/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/49Js3/29/

I don't have access to IE6, so I don't know whether it's legal. I do know you'll need an anchor to get hover behavior with CSS in IE7 and earlier.

So, I added an anchor around your image, as well as a div to contain the tooltip.

HTML

```
<div class="outer">
<a class="tippy" href="">
        <img src="" class="icon">ICON<img/>
   </a>

    <div class="demo">STUFF
        <br/>STUFF
        <br/>STUFF
        <br/>STUFF
        <br/>STUFF
        <br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.tippy {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.outer {
    width: 350px;
}
a.tippy:hover + div {
    display:block;
    float: right;
}
.demo {
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 265px;
    height: 110px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid #333;
    display: none;
}
.demo:after, .demo:before {
    border: solid transparent;
    content:' ';
    height: 0;
    right: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
}
.demo:after {
    border-width: 11px;
    border-right-color: #ccc;
    top: 13px;
}
.demo:before {
    border-width: 14px;
    border-right-color: #333;
    top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Looks great.  In order to get the left arrow to appear right next to the ICON, I added in `margin-top: -15px;` Is that what you would recommend, or would you recommend another way?  See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/49Js3/30/

Comment: This works well in Chrome, FF, IE8 and 9.  However, in IE7 the content below the div is pushed down.  Any way to avoid that?

Comment: @Keven, Typically, you add an overriding rule with different left,top values specific to IE7. You need to detect ie7 (from user-agent header) at start-up, and attach a marker class to the body element in order to do this.

Comment: So, after trying to put it into my own website, I found that the DIV actually pushes other content down in Chrome, FF, and IE when the content is longer.  I want the DIV to appear over the text.  I updated the fiddle to show you what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/49Js3/32/

Comment: @Keven Ok, I've got an update for you that fixes that: http://jsfiddle.net/49Js3/42/

Answer (score 2):

Since my reputation isn't high enough to comment on the answer above, I just wanted to add an updated fiddle (based on the above answer) that positions the tooltip absolutely, but with display: inline-block so that it is not fixed to certain position from the left and will show to the right:
here is the important bit:

```
a.tippy:hover + div {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7gmv3wo2/